# Sync Korg SQ-1 with DAW (Logic)

Tags: midi, synthesizer, daw, logic-pro, setup

I'm trying to sync my Korg SQ-1 with DAW (Logic Pro X). SQ-1 is connected via USB to computer and Logic recognizes it. I've updated MIDI settings in Logic to make SQ-1 receive MIDI clock and tempo from DAW:

`-> Preferences -> MIDI -> Sync -> MIDI Sync Project Settings -> MIDI Clock:`

[image]

Now when I click start in DAW - SQ-1 sequencer starts but there are no sequence sound playing. If I start sequencer manually it plays the sound, check the video:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/nodlgoy4z1xeqi3/korg-sq1-logic-setup.mov?dl=0

Do I miss something in Logic's setup?

Comment: useful threads on this topic - https://www.reddit.com/r/synthesizers/comments/79h0dv/help_sync_korg_sq1_with_daw/ and https://www.gearslutz.com/board/electronic-music-instruments-electronic-music-production/1126534-anyone-use-korg-sq1-logic.html#post12932008

Comment: Unfortunately, Kosmetika, the Dropbox link is no longer there so it is difficult to respond correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So my workaround looks as follows:

- connect SQ-1 to DAW via USB
- sync out Volca cable to sync in SQ-1
- set bpm in Volca with the same value as in DAW
- hit record in DAW
- hit start in SQ-1

Probably not ideal solution but works.

Answer (score 1):

In Logic 10.7.4, to send clock only, use Project Settings > Synchronization > MIDI, choose SQ-1 CTRL and check "Clock".

In my case I'm using SQ-1 to synchronize a Moog Mavis with Logic. To send MIDI notes via USB, uncheck "Clock", and use an External Instrument with MIDI Destination "SQ-1 CTRL" -- **sending clock auto-starts the SQ-1 sequencer, which disables its MIDI to CV functionality.** I find routing the Mavis audio output back to the External Instrument (which automatically turns on "Auto-compensate Latency") works like a charm for keeping Logic and Mavis in synch.